# Extract information from a text using SpaCy

Tags: nlp, spacy, information-extraction, spacy-3, spacy-transformers

**I want to build a model that extracts personal data collected by a website.**

The first step, I scrapped the privacy policy of a website, then I split it into sentences and put them on a dataframe as shown in the image below:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFIYJ.png)

From those sentences, I only want to extract those that contains the words ***"personal information"***

I used the code below but I don't get the result I want:

```
def find_names(text):

    names = []

    # spacy doc
    doc = nlp(text)

    # pattern
    pattern = [{'LOWER':'personal'},
          {'LOWER':'data'}]
            
    # Matcher class object 
    matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab) 
    matcher.add("names", [pattern]) 

    matches = matcher(doc)


    # finding patterns in the text
    for i in range(0,len(matches)):
    
        # match: id, start, end
        token = doc[matches[i][1]:matches[i][2]]
        # append token to list
        names.append(str(token))


    return names

# apply function
df2['PM_Names'] = df2['Sent'].apply(find_names)
```

**The output:**

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RJSe.png)

I want to extract the whole sentence with the words ***"personal information"*** only.

Comment: It would be easier to tell if I could have a look at your data, but I think what is happening there is that you are appending the search tokens to your df2 instead of the sentences in which they were found. And it seems to me that the main part of the issue is in this line of your code < token = doc[matches[i][1]: matches[i][2]]>

Comment: Don't use images of text/code, paste them as text.

Comment: Thank you @Anscandance for your reply, how can I show you my dataset?
I just scrapped the all the text from this link https://www.futureplc.com/privacy-policy/#5
And then I made some data cleansing, and I divided the text to different sentences, each sentence is a dataframe row

Comment: You need to debug your code, first, add print(i) under the line < for i in range(0,len(matches))>. 
Then add print(token) after <token = doc[matches[i][1]:matches[i][2]]> and you will see where the issue is, most likely. Let me know if that helps